# undefined POST and is my bcrypt system good?

Tags: php, post, sql-injection, salt, crypt

So Ive been looking arround internet to bcrypt my passwords, I got this code together from youtube, Im not sure if thats what I need since this is my first time doing such a thing.
And also I get an error saying that user, pass and mail are undefined aldo thy work fine in functions I use and in if statements above. This code is work in progress, I have yet to put salting and crypt functions in an if statement. 
Heres code:

```
<?php require_once("session.php");?>
<?php require_once("connect.php");?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["createUser"]) && isset($_POST["user"], $_POST["pass"], $_POST["mail"])){
    createUser ($_POST["user"], $_POST["pass"], $_POST["mail"]);
} 
else if(isset($_POST["userGames"])){
    userGamesUpdate ($_POST("selectedGameId"));
}
else if(isset($_POST["userLogin"])){
    login ($_POST["user"], $_POST["pass"]);
}
else if (!isset ($_POST)){
    echo "error";
}

?>
<?php 

$lenght = 21;
function random_string($lenght){

    $charset = array_merge˙(range("a", "z"), range("A", "Z"), range("0", "9"));
    shuffle($charset);
    global $randozoz;
    $randozoz = array_slice($charset, 0, $lenght);
    return implode("", $randozoz);

}
$username = $_POST["user"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];
$email = $_POST["mail"];

function prevent($wha) {

    $wha = stripslashes($wha);
    $wha = mysql_real_escape_string($wha);
    return $wha;
}

prevent($username);
prevent($password);
prevent($email);

$str = substr($username, 0, 6);
$salt = "$2a$12$".$randozoz."".$str."$";

//register
function createUser ($username, $password, $email ){
    //Get from form


    $hashedPassword = crypt($password); 
    //Submit to database
    //make query
    $query = ("INSERT INTO users ( username , email , hashPass ) VALUES ( '$username' , '$email' , '$hashedPassword')");
    //use query
    if (mysql_query($query)) {
        //userMade.php
        $query = ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'");
        $userId = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $_SESSION["userId"] = $userId;
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username; 
        header("Location: ../userMade.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "<p>".mysql_error()."</p>";
    }
}

function login ($username, $password){

    $hashedPassword = sha1($password); 
    //Submit to database
    //make query
    $query = ("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND hashPass = '{$hashedPassword}'");
    $result_set = mysql_query($query);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result_set) == 1) {
        //frontpage, session
        //$userFound = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
        $foundUser = mysql_fetch_array($result_set); 
        $_SESSION["userId"] = $foundUser["id"];
        $_SESSION["username"] = $foundUser["username"];
        header("Location: ../frontpage.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        $message = "Your username and/or password is wrong! Please try again.";
    }
}
?>
```

Login system is not integrated with crypt and salting system. But am I doing salting right?

Heres some random passwords that come out of this system:

```
$1$gc5.pn/.$txhBJZBDG3xgraJYIYY0I1
$1$8e0.vX3.$RfFLRT/iE.MXfws2fnz30.
```

And error shows in part where Im trying to protect against SQL injection, also will that system work? I dont really understand it to be honest.

Comment: Based on the hashes you are getting, this is using `MD5`, not `bcrypt`.  Also, you use `sha1` in one place and `crypt` in another.  These are not the same thing.

Comment: Looking over this a bit more, you have so many problems here that I'm not really sure where to even start..

Comment: Why not just use a cryptography library?

Comment: The answer to your second question is **no**! You can't just make up your own strings, you need to use bcrypt in order to use bcrypt.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje sh1 is used in login system that, as I said in text is not finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is full of bad things, it is hard to find a spot to start. It doesn't even work correctly.

But to answer your question on bcrypt: No, you are doing it wrong. To make it most easy for everybody using password hashing there will be a PHP Hashing API starting with PHP 5.5.

Because PHP 5.5 still is in development, there is a compatibility library that backports these functions to recent PHP versions 5.4 and down till 5.3.7. Earlier PHP have a security issue in their bcrypt implementation.

Download this library: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: I used the library you gave me, and it returns password like this:     $2y$10$16GV.bFJjsNdCzkuA.pNm.CyeqreAzxAeKVnJKncFnRiuvIGhp4.S

Comment: @user1642320 - This is the passwort hash and looks ok, `$2y` stands for BCrypt, `$10` is the cost factor, and the next 22 characters are a random salt. This value you can store in the database.